# Meta tag module not visible under individual node

Tags: 8, meta-tags

I have installed Drupal 8 on my local machine with Metatags module for SEO.

The global settings are available to edit under <kbd>Configurations → Search and Metadata → Metatag</kbd> but the Metatag tab is not visible when I edit individual articles.  I want to change the meta title and description for each article.

Comment: With "meta title", do you mean the `title` element (which is not a meta tag)? The page title usually consists of the node title (which you can edit at the node edit page) and the site name (which can be configured in your site settings). Do you want to change the site name per node?

Comment: Yes add or edit the title and meta description/keywords on node edit. Similar to the image given on   [link](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/meta-tags/) under Let's see what this does when we create a node

Answer (score 9):

When the metatag module is installed, you can create a metatag field in drupal just like creating a textfield, and can be reused in other content types.

Answer (score 1):

You must add a metatag field to the content type. Eg: www.mydomain.com/admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields/add-field
More info about metatag module in Drupal 8: https://dev.acquia.com/blog/drupal-8-module-of-the-week/drupal-8-module-of-the-week-metatag/17/02/2016/9716

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a custom html--xXx.html.twig ? Or modified the one of your theme ?

Make sure you render $page_top, $page and $page_bottom there.

Also make sure `<head-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">` is there.